# Describe all solutions of Ax=0

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I've gotten it into reduced echelon form, which was fairly simple. Adding a $b$ column that equaled zero then subtracting Line $2$ from Line $3$ times Line $1$. Thus, the $2$nd Line is all zeros and the only basic variable is $x_1$. There are infinitely many solutions given the fact that there are free variables.

I know $x_1$ can be written in terms of the free variables.
$$x_1 = -4x_2+3x_3+2x_4$$

And I figured the coefficients might be the basis for these vectors but taking that equation and setting them equal to $x_2, x_3,$ and $x_4$ will only yield $3$ coefficients for each column, when I need $4$.

> Blockquote
> $$x_1 = - 4x_2 + 3x_3 + 2x_4$$
>
> $$x_1-3x_3-2x_4= -4x_2$$
>
> $$-1/4x_1+3/4x_3+1/2x_4=x_2$$

Thus, it can't be the solution. What would be the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Comment: Seriously? A screenshot from a homework website? I think this is a new low for math stack exchange.

Comment: @MikeHaskel Why so? It's a lot simpler than typing it out in Mathjax by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you only have one equation, 
$$x_1+4x_2-3x_3-2x_4=0$$
and $$x_1=-4x_2+3x_3+2x_4$$

now take the column vector an substitute

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-4x_2+3x_3+2x_4\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\\end{pmatrix}$$

Now separate the variables
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-4x_2+3x_3+2x_4\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-4\\1\\0\\0\\\end{pmatrix}x_2+
\begin{pmatrix}
3\\0\\1\\0\\\end{pmatrix}x_3+\begin{pmatrix}
2\\0\\0\\1\\\end{pmatrix}x_4$$

Comment: What you downvote just for answering the question ?